# Getting data from JSpinner and store it into an Array

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I am currently having another problem, this time with JSpinners. I want to add dynamically JSpinners on the screen by right click, via the add button. After I add them, I want them to be inserted in an array of JSpinners and then the data from the JSpinners to be stored into a Date ArrayList. So far I am facing this problem:

- If I add a new JSpinner the Date Array does not get automatically the Date from the second JSpinner or third or so on. It only gets the data from the first JSpinner.

---

I am really lost here. Appreciate any help here.  Thanks and best regards

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class TestingGround
{
    Toolkit toolkit;
    JFrame frame;
    JPopupMenu menu;

    Calendar calendar1, calendar2;
    Date startDate, saveThisDate;
    String stringStoredInitialRequestDate;
    ArrayList <Date> dateArray; // array to store the dates from the request date
    JSpinner spinner;
    ArrayList <JSpinner> spinnerArray;
    SpinnerModel model1;


    int countAddClicks;
    int val1;

    public TestingGround()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Testing ground area");

        centerToScreen();

        menu = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem addRow = new JMenuItem("Add ComboBox");
        JMenuItem removeRow = new JMenuItem("Remove ComboBox");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel mainGridPanel = new JPanel(); 

        mainGridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
        mainGridPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        panel.add(mainGridPanel);
        // -------------------------------------------

        dateArray = new <Date> ArrayList(); // array used to store the initial request dates
        spinnerArray = new <JSpinner> ArrayList();

        JButton saveDataButton = new JButton("save state");
        countAddClicks =0;
        val1 = -1;
        panel.add(saveDataButton);

        // ACTION LISTENERS
        addRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ // Right click to add JComboBoxes to the screen
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("Starting click is: " + countAddClicks);

                    // JSPINNER 1
                    calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Date now = calendar1.getTime();
                    calendar1.add(Calendar.YEAR, -10);

                    Date startDate = calendar1.getTime();
                    calendar1.add(Calendar.YEAR, 20);

                    Date endDate = calendar1.getTime();

                    model1  = new SpinnerDateModel(now, startDate, endDate, Calendar.YEAR);

                    spinner  = new JSpinner(model1); // creating Visual Spinner 
                    String format = "dd MMM yy"; // formatting Visual Spinner 1

                    JSpinner.DateEditor editor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, format);
                    spinner.setEditor(editor); // applying the formatting to the visual spinner  

                    spinnerArray.add(countAddClicks,spinner); // adds the spinner to the array of spinners

                    /*
                    model1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    changedDate = ((SpinnerDateModel) e.getSource()).getDate();

                    }
                    });
                     */
                    saveThisDate = now;
                    dateArray.add(countAddClicks, saveThisDate); // add to the DATE array the new date (in the correct slot, going side by side with the other array);   
                    countAddClicks++;

                    System.out.println("After click is: " + countAddClicks);         

                    mainGridPanel.add(spinner); // add the JTextField to the JPanel
                    mainGridPanel.repaint();
                    mainGridPanel.revalidate();

                }
            });

        removeRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
                    countAddClicks--;  

                    if (countAddClicks <0) {
                        countAddClicks = 0;
                    }

                    if (spinnerArray.size() > 0 & dateArray.size() >0 ) {

                        spinner = spinnerArray.remove(spinnerArray.size()-1);
                        mainGridPanel.remove(spinner);
                    }

                    System.out.println("After removal click is: " + countAddClicks);
                    mainGridPanel.revalidate();      
                    mainGridPanel.repaint();

                }
            });

        saveDataButton.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                   dateArray.clear();  

                    for (int i=0; i< spinnerArray.size(); i++) {

                        JSpinner tempSpinner = spinnerArray.get(i); // creating a temporary spinner

                        calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance(); // creating a temporary calendar

                        Date now2 = calendar2.getTime(); 
                        calendar1.add(Calendar.YEAR, -50);

                        Date startDate2 = calendar2.getTime();
                        calendar2.add(Calendar.YEAR, 50);

                        Date endDate2 = calendar2.getTime();

                        SpinnerModel model2  = new SpinnerDateModel(now2, startDate2, endDate2, Calendar.YEAR);

                        tempSpinner.setModel(model2); // setting up a temporary spinnerModel and adding it to this instance of JSpinner


                        model2.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() { // adding a listener to this model2
                                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                                    saveThisDate = ((SpinnerDateModel) e.getSource()).getDate(); // checking for user input
                                    System.out.println(saveThisDate); // for testing purpose it is showing that it detects the change
                                }

                            });    




                          dateArray.add(saveThisDate); // add to the DATE array the new date (in the correct slot, going side by side with the other array);   

                        }



                    // Only for checking purpose if the arrays are the correct sizes
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("The size of the JSpinner Array is: " + spinnerArray.size() ); // showing correct
                    System.out.println("The content of the Date Array is: " + dateArray ); // checking the Date array. This is where data is not added, it is not working!
                    System.out.println("The size of the Date Array is: " + dateArray.size()); // showing correct
                    System.out.println();
                }

            });
        // Cand dau click din butonul cel mai din dreapta (3) se deschide menium popup 
        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
                    if (event.getButton() == event.BUTTON3) {
                        menu.show(event.getComponent(), event.getX(),event.getY());
                    }
                } 
            }); 

        menu.add(addRow);
        menu.add(removeRow);

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void centerToScreen()
    {
        frame.setSize(700,600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("A Popup Menu");

        toolkit = frame.getToolkit();
        Dimension size = toolkit.getScreenSize();
        frame.setLocation((size.width-frame.getWidth())/2, (size.height-frame.getHeight())/2);

    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        new TestingGround();
    }
}
```

Comment: why. I mean the questions are really well defined and clear. Don't delete, leave one question please if you really want to delete it because "too broad"...

Comment: Because these are the rules of the site. It's not a help site per se, or a "please help me complete my homework site", but rather a question and answer site, meaning your questions are supposed to be as specific as possible. Multi-part questions are not appropriate as indicated by @AndrewThompson.

Comment: modified to ask for one problem only. I cannot delete the code because it will not be clear then to search for the problem. I think the issue is in the "saveDateButton" portion, but leaving also the other code to understand all the question.

Comment: *"So far I am facing this problem:"* OK .. that is enough for me to remove the close vote. But it would be *ideal* if there was an actual question here, *"what is the code error that is causing this problem?"* or *"how do I fix this problem?"* .. and a tip: Add @HovercraftFullOfEels (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the nulls in one of the ArrayLists: You're adding null values to the `dateArray` ArrayList

```
    Date changedDate; // null


    addRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            // .....
            dateArray.add(countAddClicks, changedDate);  // changedDate is null
```

and you never change these values.  Yes you assign a ***new Date*** instance to the changedDate variable, but the ArrayList is not holding variables, it's holding *objects*.

Note that here:

```
    saveDataButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dateArray.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < spinnerArray.size(); i++) {
                //.....
                model2.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        changedDate = ((SpinnerDateModel) e.getSource()).getDate();  // **** (A) ****
                        System.out.println(changedDate);
                    }
                });
                // ...
            }
        }
    });
```

again you change the Date instance held by the dateArray variable, but again, this has no effect on the nulls held by the ArrayList.

I suggest that you get rid of the dateArray ArrayList and instead extract the data from the JSpinners when needed (in a listener).

Comment: @zypa: but do you understand the reason for the nulls as I've explained above? You're are trying to extract the Date data at the wrong time, before the user has had any chance to set it, before it's nothing but null. Instead if you need the Dates stored, extract them *within a listener* and *after* the user has set them.

Comment: I will try to fix this now. Give me some time and thanks for the update on the nulls issue. It makes sense

Comment: @zypa: what is the purpose of the dates? If a spinner is removed, is the date to be removed from the list? More background information would be very helpful.

Comment: @zypa: so you need a MVC structure where a single non-GUI model object should represent each line or row, and hold the data that is displayed in each row, as well as a "view" object, probably one that creates a JPanel that holds and displays a single row and whose state is represented by its model object,... and perhaps an ArrayList of model objects...

Comment: @zypa: don't give in to hopelessness, especially so soon. Please understand that most intense learning comes through struggle and that the harder the struggle, the greater the learning.

Answer (score 0):

@Hovercraft Full Of Eels I have solved this problem!! I am so proud, now everything works. So it adds dynamically JSpinners and stores the dates in individual Array Slots. I will paste the code if anyone will search for something similar so they can use it as a reference. Thanks again

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class TestingGround {
    Toolkit toolkit;
    JFrame frame;
    JPopupMenu menu;

    Calendar calendar1, calendar2;
    Date startDate, saveThisDate;

    ArrayList<Date> dateArray; // array to store the dates from the request date
    JSpinner spinner;
    ArrayList<JSpinner> spinnerArray;
    SpinnerModel model1;
    JPanel mainGridPanel;

    int countAddClicks;

    public TestingGround() {
        frame = new JFrame("Testing ground area");

        centerToScreen();

        menu = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem addRow = new JMenuItem("Add ComboBox");
        JMenuItem removeRow = new JMenuItem("Remove ComboBox");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        mainGridPanel = new JPanel();

        mainGridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        mainGridPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        panel.add(mainGridPanel);
        // -------------------------------------------

        dateArray = new <Date>ArrayList(); // array used to store the initial
                                            // request dates
        spinnerArray = new <JSpinner>ArrayList();

        JButton saveDataButton = new JButton("save state");
        countAddClicks = 0;

        panel.add(saveDataButton);

        // ACTION LISTENERS
        addRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // Right click to add
                                                        // JComboBoxes to the
                                                        // screen
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Starting click is: " + countAddClicks);

                // JSPINNER 1
                calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                Date now = calendar1.getTime();
                calendar1.add(Calendar.YEAR, -10);

                Date startDate = calendar1.getTime();
                calendar1.add(Calendar.YEAR, 20);

                Date endDate = calendar1.getTime();

                model1 = new SpinnerDateModel(now, startDate, endDate, Calendar.YEAR);

                spinner = new JSpinner(model1); // creating Visual Spinner
                String format = "dd MMM yy"; // formatting Visual Spinner 1

                JSpinner.DateEditor editor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, format);
                spinner.setEditor(editor); // applying the formatting to the
                                            // visual spinner

                spinnerArray.add(countAddClicks, spinner); // adds the spinner
                                                            // to the array of
                                                            // spinners

                saveThisDate = now;
                dateArray.add(countAddClicks, saveThisDate); // add to the DATE
                                                                // array the new
                                                                // date (in the
                                                                // correct slot,
                                                                // going side by
                                                                // side with the
                                                                // other array);
                countAddClicks++;

                System.out.println("After click is: " + countAddClicks);

                mainGridPanel.add(spinner); // add the JTextField to the JPanel
                mainGridPanel.repaint();
                mainGridPanel.revalidate();

            }
        });

        removeRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                countAddClicks--;

                if (countAddClicks < 0) {
                    countAddClicks = 0;
                }

                if (spinnerArray.size() > 0 & dateArray.size() > 0) {

                    spinner = spinnerArray.remove(spinnerArray.size() - 1);
                    dateArray.remove(dateArray.size() - 1);
                    mainGridPanel.remove(spinner);
                }

                System.out.println("After removal click is: " + countAddClicks);
                mainGridPanel.revalidate();
                mainGridPanel.repaint();

            }
        });

        saveDataButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                dateArray.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < spinnerArray.size(); i++) {

                    JSpinner tempSpinner = new JSpinner(); // creating a
                                                            // temporary spinner

                    calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance(); // creating a temporary
                                                        // calendar

                    Date now2 = calendar2.getTime();
                    calendar2.add(Calendar.YEAR, -50);

                    Date startDate2 = calendar2.getTime();
                    calendar2.add(Calendar.YEAR, 50);

                    Date endDate2 = calendar2.getTime();

                    SpinnerModel model2 = new SpinnerDateModel(now2, startDate2, endDate2, Calendar.YEAR);

                    tempSpinner.setModel(model2); // setting up a temporary
                                                    // spinnerModel and adding
                                                    // it to this instance of
                                                    // JSpinner

                    model2.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() { // adding a
                                                                    // listener
                                                                    // to this
                                                                    // model2
                        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                            saveThisDate = ((SpinnerDateModel) e.getSource()).getDate(); // checking
                                                                                            // for
                                                                                            // user
                                                                                            // input
                            System.out.println(saveThisDate); // for testing
                                                                // purpose it is
                                                                // showing that
                                                                // it detects
                                                                // the change
                        }

                    });

                    saveThisDate = (Date) spinnerArray.get(i).getValue();
                    System.out.println("Content of the Spinner Array is: " + spinnerArray.get(i).getValue());
                    dateArray.add(saveThisDate); // add to the DATE array the
                                                    // new date (in the correct
                                                    // slot, going side by side
                                                    // with the other array);

                }

                // Only for checking purpose if the arrays are the correct sizes
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("The size of the JSpinner Array is: " + spinnerArray.size()); // showing
                                                                                                    // correct
                System.out.println("The content of the Date Array is: " + dateArray); // checking
                                                                                        // the
                                                                                        // Date
                                                                                        // array.
                                                                                        // This
                                                                                        // is
                                                                                        // where
                                                                                        // data
                                                                                        // is
                                                                                        // not
                                                                                        // added,
                                                                                        // it
                                                                                        // is
                                                                                        // not
                                                                                        // working!
                System.out.println("The size of the Date Array is: " + dateArray.size()); // showing
                                                                                            // correct
                System.out.println();
            }

        });
        // Cand dau click din butonul cel mai din dreapta (3) se deschide menium
        // popup
        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
                if (event.getButton() == event.BUTTON3) {
                    menu.show(event.getComponent(), event.getX(), event.getY());
                }
            }
        });

        menu.add(addRow);
        menu.add(removeRow);

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void centerToScreen() {
        frame.setSize(700, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("A Popup Menu");

        toolkit = frame.getToolkit();
        Dimension size = toolkit.getScreenSize();
        frame.setLocation((size.width - frame.getWidth()) / 2, (size.height - frame.getHeight()) / 2);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestingGround();
    }
}
```

Comment: What purpose does dateArray have? All the necessary information is held within the spinnerArray, and in fact in the code above, when you decide to extract the data, you clear the dateArray (throwing out all information collected) and then re-fill it again.

Comment: Ultimately it will save the data in excel. Haven't reached that far yet... I think one more month until then.. It's going slowly. Each array will go into a different Excell row. Now the next step I will add a calculation between one date and another. In-Out and create an int result. That will eventually group by month/year and create automatic statistics. Very slick :)

Comment: Then it is still an unnecessary and dangerous duplication of data, the ArrayList version of the "parallel array" anti-pattern. I strongly urge you to get rid of dateArray, and extract the data from the components when the data is needed.

Comment: Ok. I understand the concern and will review the entire code